# Global $post returns 2 objects for my shortcode

Tags: shortcode, query-posts, globals

I made a shortcode, it does most of what I need it to do. Except for a filter I need the post id of the page the shortcode is placed. (to get some linked custom field values)
And I can't expect the persons who are going to use this shortcode to get the post ID and use in an parameter for the shortcode. So I need the shortcode itself to get it.

Simple.

```
global $post;
$post_id_i_need = $post->ID;
```

But on my testpage (id 111) $post_id_i_need returns 111307
(307 is the id of the last post that is displayed later on in loop from a wp_query)
printing the entire $post shows 2 wp post objects

```
WP_Post Object ( [ID] => 111 ... ) WP_Post Object  ( [ID] => 307 ... )
```

I also tried:

```
get_queried_object_id()
```

This gets me 111111 on echo. int(111) int(111) on var_dump.

I guess I can do something to split this up - can't figure out how.

But I was wondering if I'm missing something and if I need to get the ID some other way.

I also need it to be a shortcode (instead of a page template) as they need to be able to place it anywhere in the page with the page builder.

Comment: `get_queried_object_id()` is correct. If you're seeing it twice when printing the value it's because your code is running twice. Neither it nor the global `$post` will ever hold two values. Even if it did it would be an array, not just printed twice.

Comment: As suggested why don't you try to put a break after your calls, to check if the code in fact is running twice. From that point it would be another question.

Comment: The code that you're using to generate this output is missing from your question, please edit it to include the missing information, e.g. how did you get the double `WP_Post`? Where are you using this shortcode? How many times does it appear? Jacob is right, if it had two values it would be in an array yet it is not, so the code is running multiple times